# Print Bitmap Esc Pos

Tags: c#, printing, bitmap

I'd like to print bitmap to thermal printer via Esc/Pos.

I'm using C# but I'm looking for a correct command sequence to do that independently from the development.

I tried this example with ESC @, ESC * command

[Printing a Bit map image to pos printer via comport in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099239/printing-a-bit-map-image-to-pos-printer-via-comport-in-c-sharp)

But it not work correctly and the print (incorrect) is too slowly.

I saw there are GS command but I haven't found documentation for develop something that work...

Comment: Check my Code in [Here][1] maybe it can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22568592/1484184

Answer (score -3):

See official site of [ESC/POS Command Reference](https://reference.epson-biz.com/pos/reference/)
Registration was necessary.